# how to update a table data with enum type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying this but it doesn't work

```
update tb_traffic_log 
set 
    c_status = 'Detected' 
where 
    c_file_name = 'tj-sms-20122807-0956-000.log’;
```

kindly help

Comment: Syntax is correct, so either the row does not exist or 'Detected' is not a valid option of your ENUM

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have a typo error, you are not using single quote on the value

```
update tb_traffic_log 
set c_status='Detected' 
where c_file_name='tj-sms-20122807-0956-000.log’;
                                               ^ HERE
```

change it to `'tj-sms-20122807-0956-000.log'`

Answer (score 0):

Ohh i got the error:

Its the closing quote before the semicolon:

```
       c_file_name = 'tj-sms-20122807-0956-000.log’;
```

should be

```
       c_file_name = 'tj-sms-20122807-0956-000.log';
```